# TypeScript Promise Function Issue

Tags: typescript, promise, ionic2

I am trying to check if locally stored data exists and show/hide parts of the view accordingly. I do this by assigning true or false to formMarkersDisplay like so:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.formMarkersDisplay = this.dataService.isNearMiss(this.appGlobal.getReportPrimaryKey());
}
```

Here is the isNearMiss function:

```
isNearMiss(pk) {
    let sectionSevenObj : any;
    this.getReport(pk).then((report) => {
        if (report) {
            sectionSevenObj = JSON.parse(report);
            sectionSevenObj = sectionSevenObj.report.sections.section7;
            if(Object.keys(sectionSevenObj).length != 0) {
                this.is_markers = true;
            } else {
                this.is_markers = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return this.is_markers;
}
```

And here is getReport:

```
getReport(pk) {
  return this.storage.get(pk);
}
```

The problem is that this.is_markers gets set as false even when I am expecting true (which shows in the console.log). I have been struggling to get my head around working with Promises. I think this might be related to that.

How do I modify my code to make this work?

Comment: You need to return the promise, not the variable it mutates

Comment: There are of other problems in your code as well. For example, the type annotation on this line is not only pointless but actually prevents TypeScript from catching mistakes `let sectionSevenObj : any;`. It looks like you need to brush up on your JavaScript fundamentals given the weird things you're doing such as returning values bound to `this` from methods on the same object

Comment: I am very new to JS/TS. How do I go about returning the promise? I am looking for actual revision of my code some examples to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'll try to write up something for you later, but seriously you have many many errors in just a few lines. Like assigning in to a variable not reading its results and then assigning to something else. These are fundamentally mistakes have nothing to do with JavaScript or promises. I am not trying to discourage you but you should start with the basics. Don't start with complex frameworks like ionic and instead learn the basics of the language

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying so many things to get this working so no surprise. If u can just look at how to return promise here I will be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use promises. The issue in your code is that it's non blocking, so when you enter `this.getReport()` it executes and then along it returns the `this.is_makers` with his initial state as it is declared, it doesn't waits `this.getReport()` to finish.

For using promises you can do this:

```
isNearMiss = (pk: any): Promise<boolean> => {
  return new Promise<boolean>(ret => { //RET VAR IT'LL RETURN IN CASE OF SUCCESS
    let sectionSevenObj : any;
    this.getReport(pk).then((report) => {
      if (report) {
        sectionSevenObj = JSON.parse(report);
        sectionSevenObj = sectionSevenObj.report.sections.section7;
        if(Object.keys(sectionSevenObj).length != 0) {
            ret(true); // it'll return true
        } else {
            ret(false);
        }
      }
    });
  })
}
```

And modify your `ionViewWillEnter`

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.dataService.isNearMiss(this.appGlobal.getReportPrimaryKey()).then(ret =>{
    // DO THE CODE IF RET IS TRUE OR FALSE, LIKE SETING this.formMarkersDisplay = ret;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a ton! I understood the problem but struggled with getting the syntax right.